# Cursor to pointer when hovering

Tags: javascript, hover, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to add feature to ArcGis js map that changes cursor to pointer when hovering top of geometry. So far I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
  const pointLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    source: graphics,
    outFields: ["*"],
    renderer: UniqueValueRenderer,
    geometryType: "point",
  });

  pointLayer.on("hover", () => {
    const rendererElement = document.querySelector(
      ".esri-unique-value-renderer"
    );
    if (rendererElement !==) {
      rendererElement.style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
  });
```

pointLayer is my layer and I get the graphic on map, but hover isn't working. I also tried "visual-change" instead the "hover".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `FeatureLayer` does not have `hover` event. This kind of interaction is "done" through the view map.

So, one way to achieve what you are after is,

1. listen to the view `pointer-move` event
2. check if you are "hovering" any feature, you can do this using `hitTest` method
3. finally check in the result contains any feature from the target layer

Here is a sample of the steps previus,

```
view.on("pointer-move", function(event){
    view.hitTest(event).then(function(response){
        if (
            response.results.length
            && response.results.find(result => result.graphic.layer === targetLayer)
        ){
           // you are "hovering" some features from the target layer
        }
    })
});
```